# C2011 'Entity': 'class' type redefinition

Tags: c++

So i got this code over here:

Entity.h

```
class Entity
{
public:
    DWORD Get(int Index);

    int GetHealth(DWORD Entity);
    int GetTeam(DWORD Entity);
};
```

Entity.cpp

```
DWORD Entity::Get(int Index)
{
    return *(DWORD*)(Global_GameModule + dwEntityList + (Index * 0x10));
}
int Entity::GetHealth(DWORD Entity)
{
    return *(int*)(Entity + m_iHealth);
}
int Entity::GetTeam(DWORD Entity)
{
    return *(int*)(Entity + m_iTeamNum);
}
```

And i get this error :
Error   C2011   'Entity': 'class' type redefinition

could somebody tell me how do i solve this?

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. Also please copy-paste the full and complete build log into your question. And also add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

Comment: Can you show us a [mre]?  I suspect that the problem involves includes, header guards, and other code that you are not showing.  The code here, alone, would not produce the error you show here.

Comment: You are probably missing include guards...

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause of this is that you do not have an **include guards** in the header file(`Entity.h`).

So to solve this just add the header guards as shown below:

```
#ifndef ENTITY_H
#define ENTITY_H
class Entity
{
public:
    DWORD Get(int Index);

    int GetHealth(DWORD Entity);
    int GetTeam(DWORD Entity);
};
#endif
```

Comment: just tag one of the many dupes... or do you need more points?

Comment: @JHBonarius More points won't hurt, will they? Btw i did vote to close the question. And to answer your question as clearly as possible: "Ofcourse i do".

Comment: @zorium Please ask a separate question for your follow up question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that these 2 questions don't get mixed up.